# ControllerClientActivity.java package and other errors

Tags: android, daydream

I have just cloned the repository sample for the daydream samples. I'm looking particularly at samples-sdk-controllerclient. My questions is why is Orientation view throwing errors? below is a picture[image]

Comment: `OrientationView.class` is missing. If that class belongs to some library dependency try to rebuild the project.

Comment: as the R is also showing an error I believe a File>Invalidate cache / restart and project clean / build might help